# Can't mock website with Basic Authentication

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, mechanize, basic-authentication

Using *Ruby*, *Mechanize*, *RSpec*, and *Webmock*, I can not mock a website with Basic Authentication, my app keeps telling me that I got an unregistered stub.

**The stubs**:

```
stub_request(:get, "http://foo:bar@google.fr:80/").
     with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
     to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

Net::HTTP.start('www.google.fr') {|http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/')
  req.basic_auth 'foo', 'bar'
  http.request(req)
}
```

**In the app**:

```
url = 'http://www.google.fr'
agent = Mechanize.new 
agent.add_auth(url, 'foo', 'bar')
agent.get(url)
```

**The issue I get when running `agent.get(url)`**

```
(rdb:1) agent.get(url)
*** WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError Exception: Real HTTP connections are disabled.     Unregistered request: GET http://www.google.fr/ with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Charset'=>'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip,deflate,identity', 'Accept-Language'=>'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Connection'=>'keep-alive', 'Host'=>'www.google.fr', 'Keep-Alive'=>'300', 'User-Agent'=>'Mechanize/2.7.3 Ruby/1.9.3p194 (http://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/)'}

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:get, "http://www.google.fr/").
  with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Charset'=>'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip,deflate,identity', 'Accept-Language'=>'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Connection'=>'keep-alive', 'Host'=>'www.google.fr', 'Keep-Alive'=>'300', 'User-Agent'=>'Mechanize/2.7.3 Ruby/1.9.3p194 (http://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/)'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

registered request stubs:

stub_request(:get, "http://foo:bar@www.google.fr/").
with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'})
```

A few points:

- Assigning `'http://foo:bar@google.fr/'` to `url` does
  not work neither (and that would be very ugly if it works anyways).
- Last but not least, creating a stub with `http://www.google.fr/'` as a url would not use basic authentication, since if I do so, even if I change the credentials, I will still access to my mocked page and no errors would be rendered.

**Some screenshots:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There exists an incompatibility between WebMock and net-http-persistent.

See https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#connecting-on-nethttpstart

Add `WebMock.allow_net_connect!(:net_http_connect_on_start => true)` to your test set up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#request-with-basic-authentication) this should work:

```
stub_request(:get, "foo:bar@www.google.fr").
     with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
     to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

Comment: you are missing the `www` there, but anyways, it doesn't work neither
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/46/1415901709-lulzc.png
Thanks anwyays

Comment: weird. I added some screenshots to the first post, to show what happens for me.

Comment: @sidney, sorry I was confused because of the `Net::HTTP.start('www.google.fr') {|http|` (it is not part of the stub - it is an actual call to show that the stub works - you can safely delete it). It seems that your problem is some kind of incompatibility between mechanize and webmock, like the one shown [here](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/148)